# How to import datasets, process data and build a new database efficiently

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I have to build a database from 1260000 xml files. Each of these xml files is being processed with python, parsed, and then inserted in a certain way into the database.
This is done with the psycopg2 library.
For example I read a name, I see  if already the name is in the database and then I do the insertion or not as the case may be.
This all with python.
Each file takes about 10 minutes to run, which takes years to complete.

I wonder if there is an alternative, for what I am trying to do. (Sorry for the noob question)

Comment: 10 minutes to parse 1 XML file and load stuff into a DB? That's suspiciously slow. How big are these files?

Comment: @FMc 2 MB (the one i ran) to 400 MB

Comment: @FMc How normally this is done? And what is the average time required to do a task like this? (Database with 12 tables)

Comment: So 10 minutes for a 2MB file? Just guessing, but that seems really slow. I suggest that you first look into why your code to process one file is running at such a sluggish pace: it might be a coding/algorithm problem, or it might be a database modeling or configuration problem. Hard to say without a more specific question. An overly general question (like your current question) will probably get closed on StackOverflow. You need to ask with something more specific: actual code and an input file that illustrates the problem, so others can read the code and even run it.

Comment: Based on the long time it takes to process such a small file, my guess is that you read one line from the file, check whether that data is in the database and insert the data if its not. Am I correct?

Comment: @shish023 yes kind of...

Comment: @shish023 how should i did this?

Comment: Hard to say what the best method is without knowing more about your data. Can there be duplicates among different files? Can there be duplicates in the same file? To remove duplicates in the same file, just process you data after reading to remove the duplicates and then insert. Checking for each line is definitely not the right approach since it will make everything way too slow.

Comment: There are 2 or 3 steps: 1) Convert your thousands XMLs to several CSVs 2) Load it to DB using [`copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command 3) Fix loaded data (duplicates or something) using regular SQL.

Comment: @Abelisto there are 1260000 xmls files and theses files are not standart so i need to process it first, i don't know to to use copy command will help here, or there is a better approache? Thank very much :)